# Fetching videos Using MySql annd php

Tags: php, html, mysql, video, upload

I'm working on a website that takes a user uploaded video and puts the `name`, `size`, `type`, `path`, and `tmp_name` into a MySQL database. The `upload.php` file is below,

```
<?php 

$is_form_submitted =  (isset($_POST['submit']))?true:false;

    if($is_form_submitted)
    {
        //defines variables
        $name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
        $size=$_FILES['file']['size'];
        $tmp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $target_path="videos/";


        $allowedTypes   = array("video/wmv","video/avi",
         "video/mpeg","video/mpg","video/mp4");
        $is_valid_type  = (in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],                           $allowedTypes))?true:false;
       if ( $is_valid_type&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000000))
      {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "Upload:&nbsp; " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type:&nbsp; " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size:&nbsp; " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file:&nbsp; " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO vids(name, type, size, tmp_name, target_path)
        VALUES('$name', '$type', '$size', '$tmp_name', '$target_path')");

        if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "videos/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          echo "Stored in: " . "videos/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
          }
        }
      }
    else
    {
      echo "Invalid file";
    }

    }
?>
```

And everything uploads properly but when I go and try to fetch the name and path of the video, it says that **the video player has found no videos that are supported**, so how would I fetch a random video from the database and put it as the source of the video player?
(the video file is playable in the player, so it is not the video's fault)

Here is the php code within the document code

```
<?php

$vid_url = "videos/";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `vids` WHERE 1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo 

        <div name="video">
        <video width="100%" height="100%" controls>
        <source src=".$vid_url.$row."type="video/mp4">
     Error: Video Not working
        </object>
        </video> 
        </div>'; 

    } 
?>
```

And where I am storing the videos is a directory called videos

Comment: hey your mysql query is jibberish ... you should have something like "SELECT * FROM `vids` WHERE `{some column}`={some value}" ... as to select a random video I would suggest using an increment column for vid_id and then select a random vid_id

Comment: Why are you storing the temporary name? The temporary file will be removed by PHP when it exits, whether or not you've stored it elsewhere.

Comment: I am storing it as a reference, And @brendanmorrison, how would i know what some column and some value is?

Comment: you can use {some_colum} and {some_value} correspond to any column for eg. if you uploaded a video with the name my_test the query could look like this "SELECT * FROM `vids` WHERE `name`=`my_test`" or if you just want to find any video you could do "SELECT * FROM `vids` ORDER BY `size` DESC LIMIT 1" which will return the largest video by size in your table as I also mentioned it is probably a good idead to add a column to a table that auto increments called vid_id so each video has a specific id to help easily select them or keep as a refrence for each user but this is just an idea

Comment: I have an id column that auto increments and what I am trying to achieve is getting a random id (which would grab a random video) and then display it within the player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in case anyone wants to reference this

```
<?php    
    //Connects to database
    $host="################"; // Host name
    $username="##########"; // Mysql username
    $password="###########"; // Mysql password
    $db_name="#######"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="####"; // Table name

    // Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
    //Tells variable video where to get the name from
    $vid_url = "videos/";
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vids ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $video = $vid_url.$row["name"];
<?
```